# og:image-tag not working with addthis-button

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, sharing

We currently have a problem, where the og:image-meta tag for Facebook is not shown. We have placed the tag in the  like this: `<meta property="og:image" content="www.imageurl.com" />` - but when we share it, via the addthis-button, the wrong image is shown.

If we run it through the debug-tool: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug then it shows the correct image, but not when you share it via the share-button.

Got any suggestions as how to fix this :)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it in a different browser or a different computer?
It could be just a browser cache/history problem.

Provide the URL to your page for more insights.